# Usage of the 'abstract' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, abstract-nouns

> he loved her only in the **abstract**--not in person

[Source](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/Abstraction/en-en/)

**definition - A concept or idea not associated with any specific instance**

My question is how can he love her not in person? How is that possible?

Definition of Love(verb) -

**a person or thing that one loves.**

Maybe I don't understand abstract. If someone could help?

Also
why the symbol *--* was used? Why not something like '**;**'

Comment: It's quite possible to 'love' someone (rather, the _idea_ of someone). Think of a celebrity crush - you don't really know the person, but what they symbolise.

Comment: This is really one for PhilosophySE, but: when feelings run high, a person can have an idealised image of another person. They 'worship from afar', without having any meaningful contact with – often without having **any** contact with – the object of desire. Whether or not 'love someone in the abstract' is a contradiction in terms (ie an impossibility, a misuse of words) depends on one's definition of 'love'.